# Which one of these pipes is the drain to be used for water softener?

Tags: plumbing, water

[image]

Which one is the drain pipe where I can install the p trap and then use for water softener drain?

The bottom one says clean out on the fitting.

Comment: That leaves just one drain pipe stub, then (the high one is obviously the supply loop). What's the question?